# def Function Is Not Displaying Expected Result

Tags: python

I’m trying to get stock prices to buy or sell on specific date. When the buy price, given the sell price should be NAN. Likewise, if the sell-price is given, the buy price has to be NAN. This function and coding is originally proposed by Joseph Hart (https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/sma-short-moving-average-in-python-c656956a08f8).
The return values of the function are (sig_buy_price, sig_sell_price). My data source is Pandas DataFrame, namely qqq_df. SMA_30 and SMA_100 are samples drawn from qqq_df.
The output is not giving me the expected result, which is stated above. Please find the code indicated below.  I need specific steps and codes, to resolve the issue. I look forward to hearing from forum members. Thanks.

```
def buy_sell(qqq_df):
    sig_price_buy = []
    sig_price_sell = []
    flag = -1
    
    for i in range(len(qqq_df)):
        if qqq_df['sma_30'][i] > qqq_df['sma_100'][i]:
            if flag != 1:
                sig_price_buy.append(qqq_df['close'] [i])
                sig_price_sell.append(np.nan)
                print(qqq_df['date'][i])
            else:
                sig_price_buy.append(np.nan)
                sig_price_buy.append(np.nan)
        elif qqq_df['sma_30'][i] < qqq_df['sma_100'][i]:
            if flag != 0:
                sig_price_buy.append(np.nan) 
                sig_price_sell.append(qqq_df ['close'] [i])
                print(qqq_df['date'][i])
                flag = 0
            else:
                sig_price_buy.append(np.nan)
                sig_price_sell.append(np.nan)
        else:
            sig_price_buy.append(np.nan)
            sig_price_sell.append(np.nan)
            
    return(sig_price_buy, sig_price_sell)



b, s = buy_sell(qqq_df = qqq_df)
print(b, s)
```

Comment: You appear to have miscopied the code - your `flag != 1` block never sets `flag` to 1, so it will *always* be entered.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Can you clarify it what I supposed to do. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I missed another flag = 1 in line 11th. after inserting it, now it has printed the following output, but not the form columns. What I want is date be displayed in the first column, buy in the second column and sell in the third column.

Comment: It is printing as arrays

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me:

```
def buy_sell(data):
    sig_price_buy = []
    sig_price_sell = []
    flag = -1
    
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if data['SMA30'][i] >= data['SMA100'][i] and flag != 1:
            sig_price_buy.append(data['TSLA'][i])
            sig_price_sell.append(np.nan)
            flag = 1
        elif data['SMA30'][i] <= data['SMA100'][i] and flag != 0:
            sig_price_buy.append(np.nan)
            sig_price_sell.append(data['TSLA'][i])
            flag = 0
        else:
            sig_price_buy.append(np.nan)
            sig_price_sell.append(np.nan)
            
    return (sig_price_buy, sig_price_sell)
```

The format of the input data must be:

```
TSLA = pd.read_csv("TSLA.csv")
close = TSLA.Close

data = pd.DataFrame()
data['SMA30'] = close.rolling(window = 30).mean()
data['SMA100'] = close.rolling(window = 100).mean()
data['TSLA'] = close
```

I tested it on the TSLA stocks, so nevermind the different naming.

If you want to print it in a certain format, which I read in one of your comments, I recommend first running the function and then printing the resulting arrays formatted the way you like in a second step.

EDIT:
If you wish to access a yahoo finance stock directly from python, you can use the following framework:

```
import datetime
from os import mkdir, path
from urllib import request

def convertDateToYahooTime(date: datetime.datetime) -> int: #converts a date to a POSIX for the yahoo finance website
    return int(date.replace(hour=2, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0).timestamp())

def downloadStock(stock: str, olderDate: datetime.datetime, recentDate: datetime.datetime) -> str: #downloads a stock from yahoo finance and returns the filename
    p1: int = convertDateToYahooTime(olderDate)
    p2: int = convertDateToYahooTime(recentDate)
    link = f"https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/{stock}?period1={p1}&period2={p2}&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true"
    file = f"{stock}_{olderDate.date().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}_{recentDate.date().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}"
    if not path.exists('stocks'):
        mkdir('stocks')
    response = request.urlretrieve(link, f'stocks//{file}') #save the stock to a folder named 'stocks'
    return file

def fetchStock(stock: str, period: int) -> str: #fetches a stock and returns the filename
    today = datetime.datetime.today().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
    past = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(today.timestamp() - period*86400)
    return downloadStock(stock, past, today)
```

downladStock accesses the download link to any yahoo finance stock you want. fetchStock just makes your life easier as you can enter the name of your stock and the period of how many days of the stock you wish to access, counting backward from the present day. So if you do this:

```
STOCK = 'GOOG'
PERIOD = 1000

file = fetchStock(STOCK, PERIOD)
df = pd.read_csv('stocks//' + file)
```

df will be the google stock of the past 1000 days. You can do this to load any stock you want. after this, you can repeat the steps I mentioned above to format the stock and run the SMA30/100 algorithm on it.

I'm not sure whether this is what you wanted, but I hope it helps and you have fun with it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Dear Timangar: Thank you for your proposal to resolve the issue. I will try it by using your steps. Let you know when I test it. I will test it tomorrow or after tomorrow.

Comment: I hope it helps! Tell me how it goes, maybe we can figure this out.

Comment: Can I kindly ask you a question?  What is your data source? Are you reading ‘TSLA.csv’ from a file or reading from yf (Yahoo Finance)? If you are reading from yf, is it possible to read csv data from yf? When I tried, it gave me error, no such file.
My data source is Robinhood API, stocks.rs. It is object type data and I had to convert to float.

Comment: TSLA.csv is a file from the same folder as the python script. You CAN'T read the file directly from yf without downloading it first. However, it is possible to download it directly in python. I'll edit the answer such that you'll have a tool to download any stock from yf and use it immediately.